# Error 1064, anyone know what's wrong with this?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL QUERY BROWSER - and I have this Error 1064, anyone know what's wrong with this?

[image]

Comment: Do not use images. Provide a query as formatted code. Provide **complete** error message text. Provide **precise** MySQL version. Prediction: the version is ancient and does not support window functions.

Comment: ROW_NUM is not a mysql window function ROW_NUMBER is see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Answer (score 1):

`row_num` is not a valid MySQL window function. You probably meant to use [`row_number`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number):

```sql
SELECT department_id, salary, last_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary)
FROM   employee3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it is still not running :                                            
SELECT department_id, salary, last_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY salary)
FROM   employee3;                                                                                                                 and the error is:    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY salary)
FROM   employee3' at line  1 (error number 1064)

Comment: @Noa What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: mysql-5.0.77-server.msi                                                                                            
mysql-gui-tools-5.0.msi

Comment: @Noa MySQL 5 doesn't support window functions. If you want (need) to use such functions, you'll have to upgrade to MySQL 8

Comment: MySQL 5.0.77 was released 2009-01-28. It has been end of life since 2012. It's really time to upgrade!